# AutoMapper - Intercept member mapping for each member

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way to intercept the mapping of each property?  What I would really like to do is something like ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore(Func);

My ultimate goal is to implement column permission checking.  But I want an opt in strategy such that all fail unless secured, and I do not want to have to touch my mapping configuration if I add a column.  Rather, I would like to change my security controller that provides the condition.

Comment: probably this could help you http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't supported right now.  But, it's an interesting and quite useful feature that I'll look at for the next release.

Comment: Is this currently supported?

Comment: Nope, it is not SO makes me write 10 characters.